# Javascript analogy of cshtml @Url.Artion(Action, Controller)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

As a part of my project, I am separating cshtml script section into its own file. It mostly went successful, except for one line. Originally, view file contained the following line in the script section:

```
"sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("CertificationRun", "Certifications")", //<= part of DataTable() process
```

I talked to other programmers, and they said it would be appending line to the root directory link like `$("#RootDirectory").val() + "/ControllerName/ActionName"`

So the proper call would be `localhost/ControllerName/ActionName`

I tried this suggestion to a different section, and ended up with the following:

```
var ajSource = $("#RootDirectory").val() + "/ExpiredCert/ExpiredCertRun";

    $('.ssdatatable').DataTable({
        //irrelevant block
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500]],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sDom": "TBflrtip",
        "bServerSide": true,
        //end irrelevant block

        //"sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("CertificationRun", "Certifications")",
        //"sAjaxSource": "$(\"#RootDirectory\").val() + \"/ExpiredCert/ExpiredCertRun\" ",
        "sAjaxSource": ajSource,

       //more code
       ,
       "aoColumns": [{ "mData": "VariableName" },//more columns
                                     ]
       });
    }
```

However, upon launching, I was receiving the following error:

`DataTables warning: table id={id} - Ajax error`

After looking through official [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7), I debugged that section with suggested steps. It returned Error 500. So, before I go deeper into researching that error, **I want to make sure that I understood conversion of `@Url.Action("CertificationRun", "Certifications")` properly and properly converted it.**

That way, I will be able to eliminate some of my theories and proceed in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had a correct implementation. In order to make javascript point onto a specific action from the controller, a cshtml action code line

```
"sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

can be transformed into pure Javascript as following:

```
var ajSource = $("#RootDirectory").val() + "/ControllerName/ActionName"
```

where RootDirectory is a url string of the root directory (localhost or home page). **Which ultimately answers my question.**

In my particular case, the implementation was correct, I had a discrepancy with column naming/declaring.

Answer (score 2):

You should execute the `Url.Action` method in your razor view, which will be executed in the server and use the result of that (which is the relative url to the action method) and pass that to your js code via a global variable. Make sure you use javascript namespacing to pass the value to avoid value overwriting.

So in your razor view, you will have code like this

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};  
    myApp.urls = myApp.urls || {};       
    myApp.urls.certificateRunUrl= '@Url.Action("CertificationRun","Certifications")';
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

And your `PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js` ,you can read it like this

```
var url = myApp.urls.certificateRunUrl;
//use url for your datatable call
```

Another option is to set this to a form element and use jQuery to read this value in your external js code

```
 <div id="urls" 
           data-certificateRunUrl="'@Url.Action("CertificationRun","Certifications")" />
```

And your `PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js` ,you can read it like this

```
var url = $("#urls").data("certificateRunUrl");
//use url for your datatable call
```

This approach is useful when you need the url based on an input element in the form (Ex : For the url to get data on a input element value change event, you can keep this url in the input elements data fields)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. The original line was written in the script section of the view file, and my goal is eliminating script section of the view file all together. Is there a way to make this line into a pure js? It looks like your other option is more to what I need, can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Thank you. I will try both approaches and inform you on the progress.

Comment: If you want to take advantage of using the helper methods to generate the correct relative urls, that needs to be in the razor files because it gets executed in the server.

Comment: After more research, I found the cause (not related to question) and answered the question. My idea was correct, so I will leave my answer for someone who might need it. +1 for effort though, thank you.

Comment: @Shyju I would emphasis the data-* attribute methodology moreso than the inline script tag. Using data-* attributes are much less obtrusive than the alternative.